# Only print the parent category (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am making a blog template for my theme.
But I have one problem...

If I post a post on my blog, I only want to display the parent category of that post.

So for example, if I post a post with this category hierarchy:
- Vacation
- France
- First Day

I only want that Vacation is displayed on my blog.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Sincerely,
Joren

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $parentscategory ="";

foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
if ($category->category_parent == 0) {

$parentscategory .= ' <a href="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . '" title="' . $category->name . '">' . $category->name . '</a>, ';

}

}

echo substr($parentscategory,0,-2); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code maybe useful for you:

Display posts that have this category (and any children of that category), using category slug:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=Vacation' );
```

Or

```
$category_query_args = array(
    'category_name' => 'Vacation'
);

$category_query = new WP_Query( $category_query_args );
```

Please try and let me know.